# How can I add link as the default value for custom field in Jira?

Tags: configuration, jira, custom-fields, administration

I want to set text with link for the default value for custom field in Jira. Ex: "*Here* a link" where *here* should be a link to some service. Can I do this?

I found [instruction](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira060/configuring-a-custom-field-370705874.html#ConfiguringaCustomField-default_value) how I can edit default value of custom field.

Here is my screenshot of *Set Custom Field Defaults* page:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting

```
[here|http://example.com] a link
```

instead of the full sentence for the default value?

Comment: I wrote " <a href="http://example.com">Here</a> a link ". It seems working. Thank you.